# Short list of .prj options in .pyt

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, python-toolbox, list

I'm tasked with creating a .pyt to distribute across our office and field computers (state geological survey) for converting .gpx to features but constraining the choice of projections/datums to seven (the point being that such functionality will be more efficient). The tool must be able to write locally to a specified gdb. I'm not sure what best practices would be:  create a file in the specified .gdb with the .prj files and point to that or make the .prj variables global. Have not had success with portability either way (new to .pyt, I can fashion a script tool that works fine but is more trouble for the user than its worth). I seek insight or sample code.

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set up a filter list in your CR selection parameter.

```
    cr_parameter.parameterType = 'Required'
    cr_parameter.direction = 'Input'
    cr_parameter.datatype = 'GPString'
    cr_parameter.filter.list = ["WGS 1984",
                                "NAD 1983 NSRS2007 StatePlane California V FIPS 0405 (US Feet)",
                                ... # (etc)
                               ]
```

if the list of CRs isn't going to change much, you might as well just hard-code it. Remember also you can get `arcpy.SpatialReference` objects by name, so if you have `"WGS 1984"` in your list of CRs, you can get back to it in your script tool like this: `arcpy.sa.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")` or even `arcpy.sa.SpatialReference(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))`.

**Edit:** if you're married to the idea of using `.prj` files (and if you're not using custom projections, you shouldn't be), you could also set the `Parameter.filter.list` like this:

```
import glob

match_pattern = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*.prj')

cr_parameter.filter.list = [os.path.basename(filename) for filename in glob.glob(match_pattern)]
```

then the list would include every `.prj` file in the same folder as the `.pyt`.

Comment: Would it be possible to use parameter.filter.list to narrow down the Output Coordinate System choices that are offered in the Project tool in ArcGIS 10.2 without resorting to CR?

Comment: Not easily, you'd still need to wrap the tool yourself to get the custom validation behavior

Comment: I assumed above that the cr in cr_parameter.parameter.Type referred to Crystal Report. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I meant coordinate system

Comment: It's working using the first example of code above by removing 'cr_parameter.' except from 'cr_parameter.filter.list =' and adding 'cr_parameter.filter.type = "ValueList"'. Since we do use some projections not available in ArcGIS, I opted for hard-coding. Thanks!